# Autodesk API Forge Authentication Bearer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk, autodesk-bim360

I'm the administrator of a Bim360 Docs Hub,and i'm trying to retrieve some data from the forge API. I've already created a test app, and i get a Bim 360 Account Id.

I'm not able to get an authentication bearear token (OAuth), to make simple get requests towards projects.

Where do i get the auth token ?

Thanks

Comment: Also note that for any Bim360 api authentication you need to authenticate using 3-Leg authentication.

Answer (score 0):

See tutorial [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/oauth/v2/tutorials/http/get-2-legged-token) to aquire OAuth tokens and note that you will need different permutations of OAuth scopes (esp. `data:read data:write` etc.) for different operations, as is specified in the docs of each and every API, see an example [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/reference/http/projects-GET/#resource-information).

You may use a RESTful client like [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) to talk to our APIs and [manage the authentication flow](https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/sending_api_requests/authorization/) and [operate on response data with JavaScript](https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/scripts/test_scripts/) as you like so as to build workflows such as to [create a new project](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/tutorials/account-admin/create-project/).

Last but not least before you can access BIM360 APIs make sure you [provision access to your app](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/tutorials/getting-started/manage-access-to-docs/).

Comment: I have the "client_id", the "Bim 360 Account Id" but not "client_secret" parameter requested. Where do i find it ?

Comment: You can find it in the management panel of your Forge app. Here is a [great read](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/accounts-apps-keys-and-ids) on app administration and here’s a screenshot to help you find the secret: https://flint-prodcms-forge.s3.amazonaws.com/prod/s3fs-public/inline-images/Untitled%203.png

Comment: Found it! But i realized that in my licence, i have a trial version of Forge that expires in 300 days. After that period the app and its keys will expire too ? Are there some free Api that can i continue to use after that time ?

Comment: Far as I understand and at the time of writing your apps won’t expire but if you will need to buy Forge Credits to continue accessing the chargeable APIs (Model Derivative, Design Automation and Reality Capture) after the free credits are used up or the trial expires (whichever comes first). See [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/where-are-my-apis) for details. For pricing info pls see [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/pricing).